# create a file with 2 columns and each from various file

Tags: linux, perl, awk

how can i get the following output using perl or awk or is it possible in linux command?

file1:

```
1
2
2
4
```

file2:

```
5
6
7
8
```

Desired output:

```
1   5
2   6
2   7
4   8
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.know how to ask your question before posting it(http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: None of the answers are good enough?

Answer (score 5):

with command `paste`

```
paste  file1  file2
```

Comment: I corrected you in another answer. Please don't take it as stealing or something. Your answer is good - I even up voted you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible solution for when the lines in the file aren't fixed width would be with `pr`:

```
$ pr -mtw 10 file1 file2
1    5
2    6
3    7
4    8
```

Changing `file1` to containing variable width lines:

```
$ cat file1
The number 1
two
3
The last number is the number four

# With pr two columns are output    
$ pr -mt  file1 file2
The number 1                        5
two                                 6
3                                   7
The last number is the number four  8

# Paste simply inserts a tab which doesn't format the output in two columns
$ paste file1 file2
The number 1    5
two     6
3       7
The last number is the number four      8
```

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise:

`paste` command just prints it out. To save it to a new file the command should be:

```
paste file1 file2 > outputFile
```

`outputFile` now contains both columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with GNU parallel:

```
parallel --xapply echo '{1}' '{2}' :::: file1 :::: file2
```